# Extract Recipients Email Address in Outlook using Python Win32com

Tags: python, email, outlook, win32com

I'm trying to extract the Recipient email address in Python using Win32com client.

Here's my code so far:

```
import win32com.client

outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application").GetNamespace("MAPI")
inbox = outlook.Folders["[my email address"].Folders["Inbox"]


def get_email_address():
    for message in inbox.Items:
        print("========")
        print("Subj: " + message.Subject)
        print('To:', message.Recipients)    #this part does not work
        print("Email Type: ", message.SenderEmailType)
        if message.Class == 43:
            try:
                if message.SenderEmailType == "SMTP":
                    print("Name: ", message.SenderName)
                    print("Email Address: ", message.SenderEmailAddress)
                    print('To:', message.Recipients)    #this part does not work
                    print("Date: ", message.ReceivedTime)
                elif message.SenderEmailType == "EX":
                    print("Name: ", message.SenderName)
                    print("Email Address: ", message.Sender.GetExchangeUser(
                                                              ).PrimarySmtpAddress)
                    print('To:', message.Recipients)    #this part does not work
                    print("Date: ", message.ReceivedTime)
            except Exception as e:
                print(e)
                continue


if __name__ == '__main__':
    get_email_address()
```

As you can see, I can get the sender email address...but how do I get the recipient email address?

Comment: `Recipients` is a collection of `Recipient` objects, not a list of email addresses. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.recipients  You need to iterate through it eg `for recip in message.Recipients: print(recip.Address)`

Comment: Thanks but applying the following code as you suggested only gives me the Recipient Name, not  the Recipient Email Address.       

for message in inbox.Items:
    for x in message.Recipients:
        print(x.AddressEntry)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is similar to what you do with the sender - loop through recipients in the `MailItem.Recipients` collection and for each `Recipient` use the `Recipient.AddressEntry` property to do what you are already doing with the `MailItem.Sender`property.

Also note that this is not the most efficient way - opening an address entry can be expensive or outright impossible if the profile does not have the parent Exchange server, e.g. if you are processing a standalone MSG file or a message copied to a PST from an Exchange mailbox. In most cases the SMTP addresses are available on the message directly, e.g. from the `PidTagSenderSmtpAddress` (DASL name `http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x5D01001F`) which can be accessed using `MailItem.PropertyAccessor.GetProperty`. Similarly, recipient SMTP address might be available in the `PR_SMTP_ADDRESS` property (DASL name `http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x39FE001F`, use `Recipient.PropertyAccessor.GetProperty`) - you can see these properties in [OutlookSpy](https://www.dimastr.com/outspy) (I am its author - click IMessage button property).

Comment: It seems that this doesn't work - for message in inbox.Items: for x in message.Recipients: print(x.AddressEntry).  I don't care about the efficiency as much - I just need a simple code to quickly solve this annoying problem.

Comment: `print(x.AddressEntry)` is meaningless - it is an object, not a property. You need `print(x.AddressEntry.GetExchangeUser().PrimarySmtpAddress)`

Comment: Thank you for your help!

Comment: @DmitryStreblechenko, I tried the code you mentioned above. ```x.AddressEntry``` returns the name correctly but the next code ```print(x.AddressEntry.GetExchangeUser().PrimarySmtpAddress)``` returns none. So any idea of fixing it?

Comment: TRy to read `http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x39FE001F` using `Recipient.PropertyAccessor.GetProperty` - `GetExchangeUser` won't work if there is no connection to Exchange or if the entry is no longer in GAL.