# Extract the Group Email Address from the recipients of outlook email using win32

Tags: python, outlook, pywin32, win32com, office-automation

I'm trying to extract the all email info from outlook such as email body, sender address and the recipients addresses.

The extraction of the sender and body works fine but unable to get the recipents email addresses as the recipients list contains group emails which results none while extracting the address whereas it returns the names correctly.

Here is the code

````
otlk = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application")
outlook = otlk.GetNamespace("MAPI")
email_sender = outlook.Session.Accounts['pravin.subramanian@alatas.com']

for i in (range(len(outlook.Folders))):
    #Condition to take emails from that particular account.
    if (outlook.Folders.Item(i+1).Name == 'autoenq@xyz.com'):
        root_folder = outlook.Folders.Item(i+1)
        #Looping to find the inbox folder and extracting the emails
        for folder in root_folder.Folders:
            if (folder.Name == 'Inbox'):
                messages = folder.Items
                messages.Sort("[ReceivedTime]", True) 
                msg_no = 0
                for message in messages:
                    #Trying to get the recipients email
                    recipients = message.Recipients
                    for recipient in recipients:
                        print(recipient.AddressEntry.GetExchangeUser())
                        #recipient.AddressEntry.GetExchangeUser().PrimarySmtpAddress```

But the code returns none whereas if I tried ```recipient.AddressEntry``` it returns the names of the recipients correctly??

How can I fix this?
````

Answer (score 0):

Yu need to check the [AddressEntry.AddressEntryUserType](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.addressentry.addressentryusertype) property value to determine the type of address entry before calling the `GetExchangeUser` method. The property returns a constant from the [OlAddressEntryUserType](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.oladdressentryusertype) enumeration representing the user type of the `AddressEntry`. In case of Exchange distribution lists you may call the [GetExchangeDistributionList](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.addressentry.getexchangedistributionlist) method which returns an `ExchangeDistributionList` object that represents the `AddressEntry` if the `AddressEntry` belongs to an Exchange `AddressList` object such as the Global Address List (`GAL`) and corresponds to an Exchange distribution list.

For example, the following VBA sample shows how you may check the recipient type:

```
Sub DemoAE() 
 Dim colAL As Outlook.AddressLists 
 Dim oAL As Outlook.AddressList 
 Dim colAE As Outlook.AddressEntries 
 Dim oAE As Outlook.AddressEntry 
 Dim oExUser As Outlook.ExchangeUser 
 Set colAL = Application.Session.AddressLists 
 For Each oAL In colAL 
   'Address list is an Exchange Global Address List 
   If oAL.AddressListType = olExchangeGlobalAddressList Then 
     Set colAE = oAL.AddressEntries 
     For Each oAE In colAE 
       If oAE.AddressEntryUserType = olExchangeUserAddressEntry Then 
         Set oExUser = oAE.GetExchangeUser 
         Debug.Print(oExUser.JobTitle) 
         Debug.Print(oExUser.OfficeLocation) 
         Debug.Print(oExUser.BusinessTelephoneNumber) 
       End If 
     Next 
   End If 
 Next 
End Sub
```

Also to access the required store in Outlook instead of using the following code:

```
email_sender = outlook.Session.Accounts['pravin.subramanian@alatas.com']

 if (outlook.Folders.Item(i+1).Name == 'autoenq@xyz.com'):
```

You can use the [Stores](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.namespace.stores) property of the `Namespace` class which returns a `Stores` collection object that represents all the Store objects in the current profile.

Then you can use the [Store.GetDefaultFolder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.store.getdefaultfolder) method which returns a `Folder` object that represents the default folder in the store and that is of the type specified by the `FolderType` argument. This method is similar to the `GetDefaultFolder` method of the `NameSpace` object. The difference is that this method gets the default folder on the delivery store that is associated with the account, whereas `NameSpace.GetDefaultFolder` returns the default folder on the default store for the current profile.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you cannot print a COM object - it is an object, not a scalar value, so the line

```
print(recipient.AddressEntry.GetExchangeUser())
```

must be changed to

```
print(recipient.AddressEntry.GetExchangeUser().PrimarySmtpAddress)
```

You need to check that `AddressEntry.GetExchangeUser()` returns a valid object - it will be null if the address entry does not reside in GAL, e.g. if it is a one-off external (SMTP) address. `recipient.AddressEntry` can also return null or an error, e.g. if the address entry cannot be opened  - e.g. if it belongs to a GAL account and your current profile does not contain an Exchange server.

Your best bet is reading `PR_SMTP_ADDRESS` property using `Recipient.PropertyAccessor.GetProperty` and falling back to `recipient.AddressEntry.GetExchangeUser()` only if nothing else worked.

See [Extract Recipients Email Address in Outlook using Python Win32com](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70276607/extract-recipients-email-address-in-outlook-using-python-win32com/70278431#comment133690391_70278431)